# where is certificate chain in PDF

Tags: java, pdf, adobe, digital-signature, pdfbox

I've just signed a document. The signer certificate has one issuer intermediate certificate and intermediate's issuer is the root certificate.

I sign document and I see the full chain of that certificate. But when I see in PDF explorer, there is only Signer certificate:

[image]

I need that certificate chain. I'm going to get them using PDFbox, but I have no idea where it is.

Comment: Where do you see the full chain? In Adobe Reader? That may be because the Reader has the certificates in its own stores. Or retrieves them from the OS's store. Or retrieves them via LDAP from some remote directory server indicated in the user certificate... Please supply the PDF in question if you want to know for sure. But if you want to embed all required certificates, you generally will have to tap other resources than merely the PDF in question. If you also control the original signing routine, though, you might enforce complete certificate chain embedding there and then.

Comment: I fount my certificate in Store of org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSSignedData.

Comment: `CMSSignedData` is just a helper class allowing to dissect and build the signatures that **Contents** key. Thus, the certificates actually are where you pointed at in your graphic... ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can find code to show the certificate chain in the ShowSignature.java example in the examples subproject of the PDFBox source code [download](https://pdfbox.apache.org/download.cgi) or in the [repository](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/pdfbox/branches/2.0/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/signature/ShowSignature.java?view=markup).

Here's some code reduced from there, which is only applicable for certain signature subtypes (adbe.pkcs7.detached and ETSI.CAdES.detached, the others can be seen in the mentioned example):

```
try (PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(file))
{
    for (PDSignature sig : document.getSignatureDictionaries())
    {
        COSDictionary sigDict = sig.getCOSObject();
        COSString contents = (COSString) sigDict.getDictionaryObject(COSName.CONTENTS);
        CMSSignedData signedData = new CMSSignedData(contents.getBytes());
        Store<X509CertificateHolder> certificatesStore = signedData.getCertificates();
        JcaX509CertificateConverter certificateConverter = new JcaX509CertificateConverter();
        Collection<X509CertificateHolder> matches = certificatesStore.getMatches(null);
        System.out.println("Certificates in chain: " + matches.size());
        System.out.println();
        int n = 0;
        for (X509CertificateHolder certificateHolder : matches)
        {
            ++n;
            X509Certificate certificate = certificateConverter.getCertificate(certificateHolder);
            System.out.println("Certificate " + n + ":");
            System.out.println(certificate);
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

The ShowSignature.java example has much more to offer: it checks the signature validity, whether the signature covers the whole document and (new in 2.0.13) checks the whole certificate chain including revocation (OCSP or CRL).